# How to see how many commits a local branch is ahead/behind another local branch in git?

Tags: git

If I'm working on a feature branch, I would like to know how many commits this branch is ahead or behind the master branch. I can't seem to find the command that does this.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

#### Listing and counting commits: `git rev-list`

A quick way is to do what `git status` does when there's an "upstream".  Specifically, `git status` simply counts revisions that are on the current branch that are not on the upstream branch.  For instance, consider branch `foo` that has an upstream of `origin/foo`, and suppose you've made three local commits and then used `git fetch` to bring in one upstream commit:

```
              L - L - L   <-- foo
            /
... - C - C
            \
              U           <-- origin/foo
```

Here `C`s are common commits, `L`s are local commits, and `U` is an upstream commit.  If you're on branch `foo` and you run `git status` you'll see "ahead 3, behind 1".

Here's how git gets those numbers:

1. `git rev-list foo --not origin/foo`: this produces a list of all commits on `foo` but not on `origin/foo`.  That is, starting at `origin/foo` (which is commit `U`), strike out the commit and all earlier commits reachable: that's `U` and all the `C` commits.  Then, start at `foo` and find all reachable commits that are not already struck out: that's just the three `L` commits.
2. Add `--count` to the `git rev-list` arguments to make it print a count instead of the raw commit-ID SHA-1 values.
3. Repeat for `git rev-list origin/foo --not foo`: this is all commits that are reachable from `origin/foo` but not from `foo`, which in this example is just commit `U`.  (Again, add `--count` to get just the count, rather than the actual commit IDs.)

Note that `foo --not origin/foo` is also spelled `origin/foo..foo` in [gitrevisions](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitrevisions.html) syntax.  (In the case of `git status` it's always looking at the *current* branch—which is named via `HEAD`—and its upstream.  You can use the `@{upstream}` syntax to obtain the name of the upstream, or shorten this to `@{u}`; and `HEAD` is the default if you list no name at all; so to re-implement `git status` you can just look at `git rev-list --count ..@{u}` and `git rev-list --count @{u}..`.)

#### Using `rev-list` on local branches, vs using `git cherry`

Hence, if you want to count commits reachable from branch `feature` but not from branch `master`, you can do the same thing but with the names `feature` and `master`.  The `git rev-list` syntax `master..feature` names all commit IDs reachable from `feature` but not from `master`, and `--count` will get you a count:

```
git rev-list --count master..feature
```

If you've cherry-picked some commits from one branch to another, though, so that they have different commit IDs but the same diff, this will "over-count".  For instance suppose `feature` had five commits that `master` did't, but then you (or someone) had decided that one of those five commits should be cherry-picked into `master`, you might now have this:

```
              D - E - F - G - H   <-- feature
            /
... - C - C
            \
              F'                  <-- master
```

where `F'` is basically just a copy of commit `F`.  If you ask `git rev-list` to count commits on `feature` that are not on `master`, you'll get 5; but if you ask `git cherry` to find commits on `feature` that are not on `master`, it will eliminate commit `F` from its list, because it will see that `F'` is a copy of `F`.  If you count the commits listed by `git cherry` you will therefore get 4, not 5.

Comment: So then would you say it is better (or more accurate) to cherry over rev-list?

Comment: @Red2678: it's better if you want that number; it's worse if you want the other number. That is, did you want to count *commits*, or *commits that have different patch-IDs?*

Comment: @torrek I see what ya did there ;) I guess it really does depend on the situation then. If cherry-picking is common practice in the env. then you would want to make sure that you count them. With that being said, I guess I could then say then that using cherry would be "more accurate"  if you do not know if someone was cherry-picking in commits.

Answer (score 12):

Use `git cherry` to find the commits present in one branch and not present in other

```
git cherry -v master feature
```

It will list all the commits present in feature branch which are not present in the master.

Similarly,

```
git cherry -v feature master
```

will list all the commits present in master branch which are not present in feature.

You can also provide an additional third parameter for picking a starting point.

```
git cherry -v feature master 1b219e
```

**UPDATE:**

You can create an alias to combine the two

```
[alias]
    mydiff = !sh -c 'echo "Commits in $2 not in $1" && git cherry -v $1 $2 && echo "Commits in $1 not in $2" && git cherry -v $2 $1' -
```

Use,

```
git mydiff master feature
```

Comment: Cool, thanks. Is there a way to also get a count all in one, how many ahead, how many behind?

Comment: you can create an alias

Comment: Note that `git cherry` actually compares diffs, so it's fancier than `git status`'s method, which I'll write up in a separate answer.

Comment: @Blossoming_Flower I realize this is late to post, but I needed this myself, so what I did was combine the alias above and piping it to wc -l which counts lines of output. my alias is set up as `[alias]
    cdiffcount = !sh -c 'echo "Commits in $2 not in $1: " && git cherry $1 $2 | wc -l && echo "Commits in $1 not in $2: " && git cherry $2 $1 | wc -l' - `